# Chances of Hidden Ability through breeding, as well as chances for gender

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Does having both parent Pokemon, of the same species and with Hidden Abilities, increase the chances of getting a baby Pokemont hat has said Hidden Abilities or does it simply have the same chance with a single parent with Hidden Abilities and a Ditto?

Moreover, I want to have a Ralts which has telepathy and so far, I had used the latter method (Male Ralts with Hidden Abilities and Ditto) and I only get male Ralts with Hidden Abilities and no female Ralts so far.

Is having a gender specific Pokemon a deciding factor if the egg would be a male or female variant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does having both parent Pokémon, of the same species and with Hidden Abilities, increase the chances of getting a baby Pokémon that has said Hidden Abilities?

**No**. Whilst both Male and Female Pokémon have a chance to pass on their Hidden ability in Gen 6, Male Pokemon will only have this chance to pass it on **when breeding with Ditto**. When breeding with the same species, only the Female's Hidden Ability matters.

> Is having a gender specific Pokémon a deciding factor if the egg would be a male or female variant?

**No**, each Pokemon type has a specific ratio to be a specific Gender. The most common is a 50/50 chance to be either Gender (which your [Ralts](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ralts_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) has):

[image: Ralts' stats]

There are also Pokemon that have more skewed results toward a specific gender. [Eevee](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eevee_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) for example, has an 87.5% chance to be Male. There are also Pokemon that are *always* one Gender like [Kangaskhan](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kangaskhan_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), *and* Pokemon that are Genderless, like [Metagross](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Metagross_(Pok%C3%A9mon)). (These must be bred with Ditto, they cannot reproduce with a member of the same species).

You should have a look at Bulbapedia's [Breeding Guide](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_breeding), as it covers a lot of ground about Egg groups, getting Egg Moves, Hidden Abilities, IVs and other useful info.