# Can an Aipom pass on it's Hidden Ability to Minccino, given that they have the same Hidden Ability?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

I read that both Aipom and Minccino posses the same Hidden Ability Skill Link. So, is it possible for a male Aipom with Skill Link and a female Minccino without the HA to have a Minccino having the Hidden Ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

As I covered on your [last question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/263195/28182), Male Pokemon only have a chance to pass on their Hidden Ability (HA) when bred with **Ditto**. Even if they share the same ability, your male HA Aipom and Female Non-HA Minccino will not produce a Minccino with it's Hidden Ability.

In order to obtain a Hidden Ability Minccino, you will have to either

- Trade for one
- Transfer one up from 5th Gen (obtained from the Dream World)
- Have a Normal-type [Friend Safari](http://www.serebii.net/xy/friendsafari.shtml) in X or Y where Minccino will appear, and catch it there.

---

Think of Abilities like 'slots' rather than what the actual ability might be. Most Pokemon have two regular Ability slots, and one Hidden Ability slot.

Minccino as an example, has:

- **Slot #1**: Cute Charm
- **Slot #2**: Technician
- **Hidden Slot**: Skill Link

As a female, Minccino has an 80% chance of passing down its Ability slot. If your female Minccino has Cute Charm, then it has a 80% chance of passing on Cute Charm. The rest of the percentage will be randomly chosen between the two **normal** slots, i.e. Cute Charm and Technician. Only when it **has** it's Hidden ability will it have a chance to pass it on.

You can read more about Ability inheritance on [Bulbapedia's Breeding Guide](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_breeding#Inheriting_Abilities)